# Docker not releasing memory when shutdown, windows 10

Tags: docker, windows-10, hyper-v

I have recently started using docker for new development work, however I am still required to switch back to working on our older on-premise offering from time to time. That is, I sometimes need to shutdown docker and spin up a an installation of our on premise server.

I find that when I do this with docker installed the performance of this server is terrible, essentially unusable, I need to uninstall docker to get it to work again.

When I have docker running I can see it using the memory (my machine has 32 GB of RAM, I am telling docker to use 16) and when I shutdown docker I can see it being released, according to the task manager anyway, and I can also see on hyper-v manager that the VM has been shutdown. However the performance of on-premise server install continues to act as the memory is in use. This is not a small performance hit, actions that should take 1 second take 20 or 30.

It would seem like docker is not actually releasing the memory on shutdown and only does so when I actually uninstall it, when I do this performance recovers completely.

Is this a known issue? Is there anything else I can try to see where the memory is going? I can find no other reports about it.

I am using windows 10 with docker version 17.03.1-ce-win5 (10743)

Comment: Can you update your question to explain more about how you use the application? Are they both running on the same machine? Is Docker running in a hyper-v VM or is it installed some other way (what do you mean by "uninstalling")? Is the performance always exactly 20-30 seconds? How is the application accessed (is it a web application)? When you run it in Docker, do you shutdown the existing on premise server and share a DNS name or port on the host? My first instinct is that maybe there is a lingering DNS or port issue causing some sort of timeout (especially if the performance is predictable).

Comment: Hi, both are running on the same machine, docker is running on a hyper-v VM on a windows 10 machine. By "uninstall" I mean I use windows "add or remove programs" to remove it. The performance is not predictable, I was trying to say that it used to be very responsive and now it is extremely slow, it occasionally times out on some calls but is generally just slow. Also, I am not running the same thing in docker and not in docker, I thought that was the issue initially but even with a freshly installed version of docker with nothing on it just installing it and then shutting it down I see this.